# Use jQuery to find any URL or Sub-URL

Tags: jquery

Starting over:

I have a `<select>` that has four options, for four different categories. When a user visits one of the categories, the appropriate `<option>` gets selected in the `<select>`. So for example, if I'm viewing a category named "Category Name", the "Category Name" `<option>` is selected in the `<select>` menu

These four different categories can each have multiple pages within the categories. The URL for the first page of these categories is `/category-name/`, the second page of these categories is `/category-name/page/2/`, and so on. My `<select>` only has options for the main categories, not every page within each category.

I need to find a way to detect if a user is on the name `/category-name/` page, or any sub-page, such as `/category-name/page/2/`.

This is the script I'm currently using:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$("#restaurantSelect option[value=\"" + pathname + "\"]").attr("selected","true");
```

How can I modify that to work the way I need it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function into [jQuery's filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.  That should make it easy to perform any custom checks you want.

```
var $optionsWithPage = $("#restaurantSelect option").filter(function(){
    return /\/page\/\d+/ig.test($(this).attr("option"));
});
```

**EDIT** - based your re-write (an aside - please avoid re-writing your question after people have provided answers), I would suggest you tweak the above regex as needed.  I *think* it should be something like this:

```
/category-name(\/page\/\d+\/)?/
```

Comment: I just re-wrote my question, I think you misunderstood what I was trying to do. Hopefully I'm more clear now.

Comment: Sorry about the re-write, just felt like it was such a big edit that I re-write was required. I'm pretty horrible with regular expression stuff, makes no sense to me. The code you provided seems to work fine for the main categories, but not the sub-pages still. Not sure why. Is this what the line should look like? `return /pathname(\/page\/\d+\/)?/.test($(this).attr("option"));`

Comment: If pathname is a variable, and not a literal string, then no.  You'll have to create a RegEx object that'll allow you to put vairables in.  The syntax is less friendly though. Something like new `RegExp(pathname + "\\/page\\/\\d+/");`  If you have trouble with it, I'd create a new question.  I gotta get some work of my own done :)